# What is a simple command/process I can run to prevent Ubuntu from sleeping?

Tags: 14.04, suspend, scripts

I want to make simple "sleep" script for Ubuntu. So I can watch Hulu and the machine will not suspend or turn off the display.

I think I can figure out most of it, but this part I don't even know where to start.

I need a simple command or process I can start, that will keep the computer awake, and the screen on, until I kill. So that I can run this for as long as I want the computer on then after that time it will go to sleep like normal.

Not sure if I explained that well, let me know if it needs clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could install and use [Caffeine](https://launchpad.net/caffeine).
It does what you want.

But if you want a command to do that without installing anything, check 
out `gnome-session-inhibit`.
If you're using Unity or GNOME (and maybe others), it should do what you want.

Check the man page of that command.

- `gnome-session-inhibit gedit`: should open *gedit* and inhibit the lock screen 
  from activating.
- `gnome-session-inhibit --inhibit suspend:idle gedit`: should also inhibit suspend.
- `gnome-session-inhibit --inhibit suspend:idle --inhibit-only`: should do the
  same until <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is pressed, without opening *gedit*.

Comment: Perfect, `gnome-session-inhibit`. I wanted to avoid installing anything, because I figured there was a simple way. Thanks